# What does it mean "Distance between $k$-planes induced by the identification plane-projection matrix"?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, calculus-of-variations, geometric-measure-theory

I'm reading some parts of *Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems* by Ambrosio, Fusco, Pallara.

At the very beginning of page 82 there's written "*Let $G_k$ be the complete metric space of unoriented $k$-planes on $\mathbb R^n$, with the metric $d(\pi,\pi')=|\pi-\pi'|$ coming from the identification plane-projection matrix.*" 
So we want to define a distance between $k$-planes in $\mathbb R^n$, but I don't understand what "metric coming from plane-projection matrix" means. 
It is probable that this definition is written somewhere in the book and I've missed it, but I can't find it.

Could it be something like this: 
$$d(\pi,\pi')=\inf \{|x-\pi(x)|:x\in \pi'\}$$ (by $\pi(x)$ I mean the orthogonal projection of $x$ on $\pi$)?

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the Grassmann metric, discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian#The_Grassmannian_as_a_homogeneous_space).  The idea is to define the distance between planes as the distance between the projection operators onto their shifted subspaces, using the operator norm.  Recall that a $k$-plane is just a shifted subspace, i.e. $\pi$ is of the form $W+a$ where $W$ is some $k$-dimensional subspace.  We then define

$$
d(\pi,\pi^\prime) = \|P_W-P_{W^\prime}\|
$$  Here $P_W,\;P_{W^\prime}$ are the projections onto to the $k$-dimensional *subspaces* $W=\pi-a$ and $W^\prime = \pi^\prime-a^\prime$, respectively.  This isn't particularly clear from their notation.

Here's a bad picture illustrating the idea:

[image]

You project points onto the two (shifted) planes, then find the largest that this can be.  This picture isn't quite right because the planes should intersect the sphere, i.e. the projection points should be on the sphere.  You're esstially finding the Hausdorff distance of the intersection of these subspaces with the unit sphere -  see also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48118/a-metric-for-grassmannians) mathoverflow post.

Comment: So $d(\pi,\pi')=\sup \{\frac{|P_\pi(x)-P_{\pi'}(x)|}{|x|}:|x|\leq1\}$?

Comment: That would be one way to define it, correct. I tend to prefer to sup over the unit sphere (i.e. $\vert x\vert = 1$), but either works. Presumably they're working with the Euclidean inner product, i.e. $\vert x-y\vert$ means the usual thing, but if they had some strange inner product you'd have to be slightly more careful.

Comment: See edit - I wasn't quite careful enough at first.  You use the projection onto the subspaces, not onto the planes themselves.  The projection onto the shifted plane isn't a linear operator so you can't do an operator norm on it.

Comment: But what is the meaning of this metric? I can't see the intention behind this definition. For example, if $\pi $ and $\pi'$ intersect, is $d(\pi,\pi')=0$? And also, I was taking for granted that a $k$-plane is $k$-dimensional *subspace*.

Comment: I posted a picture and a link to a MO post, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it is clearer:)